# Getting NSURL to file in subdirectory

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsbundle

I'm integrating a third-party SDK for voice messaging. It saves audio files to Documents/audio/. I've peeked into the bundle on my test device using iFunBox and found the files are named like this: "b3abwx78...wav". There is no file extension, the end of the name is just "wav", rather than ".wav", which could be causing my issues. The SDK I'm using is proprietary and doesn't give me any control over how the files are saved.

The file is referenced by the SDK as "elem.text", which logs as something like this: "audio://a8c0cd0c4138d66cc32cbdfb3c213f3bwav"

So, what I'm trying to do is simply load that file into AVAudioPlayer and play it. Here's what I'm trying so far. "path" logs as null, as does URL, so obviously I've done something wrong:

```
-(void)playVoiceMail:(NSString *)filename
{
NSError *error;
NSString *escapedFilename = [filename stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 8) withString:@""];
NSLog(@"escaped filename: %@", escapedFilename);

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:escapedFilename
                                                 ofType:nil
                                            inDirectory:@"Documents/audio"];

NSLog(@"path: %@", path);

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:path];

NSLog(@"URL: %@", URL);


AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL
                                                               error: &error];

NSLog(@"Player url: %@", player.url);

if (error)
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error.localizedDescription);

if (!player.playing)
    if (![player play])
        NSLog(@"ERROR playing");
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you saving the files? For the simulator it should be something like /Users/petersegerblom/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/2CF53DC0-5C06-4810-9C01-78D5F6855688/ProjectName.app this would be the path for your bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Were are you stocking the audio files ? if they are stored in your application bundle, try a code like this :

```
...
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:escapedFilename
                                                 ofType:nil];
...
```

If they are stored in the Documents folder, you should access them like this :

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename"];
NSURL *url ....
```

EDIT : If your url is not null, the then problem is With ARC, the AudioPalyer instance is released after the playVoiceMail method reaches the end. You should create a strong property like this :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *player;

...
self.player= [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL
                                                               error: &error];

[self.player play];
...
```

Comment: Thank you, that definitely got me closer. I now appear to be getting a URL loaded into the player, but I still can't hear anything (yes I made sure my volume is up and phone is not on silent, haha). My audio player's url property logs like so: "Player url: /var/mobile/Applications/FF99CE15-E04E-4ADD-985F-F23B3038FFAE/Documents/audio/ae321148ba09f8991a7abdb51ab9b022wav"

Does this look right? Any idea why it's not playing? Maybe I need to use NSFileManager to add the .wav extension myself?

Comment: i think that your problem is ARC. The AudioPlayer object is releases after the method playVoiceMail is finished. you should declare a property for your audion player. @property(nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer; and use it to play the audio. See my edit

Comment: I don't think that would matter, though, since the player is recreated each time the method is called. If the player releases after it's done playing, should be fine. I'll give it a shot anyway, though. Thanks!

Comment: sure that it will recreated of each call, but if the sound file is about 10 minutes then the player object will be released just after the end of the method. If your path is correct, then you have to fix the ARC problem by creating a strong reference to your AVAudioPlayer :)

Comment: Well I'll be damned...you were right! Holding onto a reference does the trick. I would not have expected that. Thank you!!